# Matlab Mex: "Shared Matrix" including BOOST compilation error

Tags: matlab, boost, mex

I use matlab a lot but not too much C(which I will get into later). I am trying to install a mex file called [SharedMatrix](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28572-sharedmatrix). The installation requires Boost's interprocess libraries.

To install SharedMatrix on Matlab I input:

```
mex -v -O -win32 -I'C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51' SharedMemory.cpp
```

The exact output I get is:

```
*************************************************************************** 
  Warning: Neither -compatibleArrayDims nor -largeArrayDims is selected.  
           Using -compatibleArrayDims. In the future, MATLAB will require 
           the use of -largeArrayDims and remove the -compatibleArrayDims  
           option. For more information, see: 
           http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/bsflnue-1.html 
**************************************************************************** 

-> Default options filename found in C:\Users\Skyhr\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2012b 
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
->    Options file           = C:\Users\Skyhr\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2012b\mexopts.bat 
      MATLAB                 = C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b 
->    COMPILER               = lcc 
->    Compiler flags: 
         COMPFLAGS           = -c -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\sys\lcc\include" -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -noregistrylookup 
         OPTIMFLAGS          = -DNDEBUG 
         DEBUGFLAGS          = -g4 
         arguments           =  -I"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51" 
         Name switch         = -Fo 
->    Pre-linking commands   =  
->    LINKER                 = lcclnk 
->    Link directives: 
         LINKFLAGS           =  -tmpdir "." -dll "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win32\lcc\mexFunction.def" -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\sys\lcc\lib" -libpath "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win32\lcc" "C:\Users\Skyhr\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_5NkIuB\templib2.obj" 
         LINKDEBUGFLAGS      =  
         LINKFLAGSPOST       = libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib 
         Name directive      = -o "SharedMemory.mexw32" 
         File link directive =  
         Lib. link directive =  
         Rsp file indicator  = @ 
->    Resource Compiler      = lrc -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\sys\lcc\include" -noregistrylookup -fo"mexversion.res" 
->    Resource Linker        =  
---------------------------------------------------------------- 


--> lcc  -I"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51" -c -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\sys\lcc\include" -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -noregistrylookup -FoC:\Users\Skyhr\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_5NkIuB\SharedMemory.obj -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\simulink\include" -DNDEBUG -DMX_COMPAT_32 SharedMemory.cpp 

lcc preprocessor error: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp:21 C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\mapped_region.hpp:17 .\SharedMemStack.hpp:9 .\SharedMemory.hpp:92 SharedMemory.cpp:62 Could not find include file <cstddef> 
lcc preprocessor error: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp:38 C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\mapped_region.hpp:17 .\SharedMemStack.hpp:9 .\SharedMemory.hpp:92 SharedMemory.cpp:62 Could not find include file <utility> 
lcc preprocessor error: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp:39 C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\mapped_region.hpp:17 .\SharedMemStack.hpp:9 .\SharedMemory.hpp:92 SharedMemory.cpp:62 Could not find include file <memory> 
lcc preprocessor error: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp:40 C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\mapped_region.hpp:17 .\SharedMemStack.hpp:9 .\SharedMemory.hpp:92 SharedMemory.cpp:62 Could not find include file <functional> 
lcc preprocessor error: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp:41 C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\mapped_region.hpp:17 .\SharedMemStack.hpp:9 .\SharedMemory.hpp:92 SharedMemory.cpp:62 Could not find include file <iosfwd> 
lcc preprocessor error: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp:42 C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\mapped_region.hpp:17 .\SharedMemStack.hpp:9 .\SharedMemory.hpp:92 SharedMemory.cpp:62 Could not find include file <string> 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 28  syntax error; found `boost' expecting `;' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 28  syntax error; found `{' expecting `;' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 28  skipping `{' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 29  syntax error; found `intrusive' expecting `;' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 29  syntax error; found `{' expecting `;' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 29  skipping `{' `}' `}' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 32  syntax error; found `boost' expecting `;' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 32  syntax error; found `{' expecting `;' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 32  skipping `{' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 33  syntax error; found `interprocess' expecting `;' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 33  syntax error; found `{' expecting `;' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 33  skipping `{' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 34  syntax error; found `bi' expecting `;' 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 34  initializer must be constant 
Error SharedMemory.cpp: C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp: 34  too many errors 

  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'SharedMemory.cpp' failed.
```

Could you please
1. Explain the error
2. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

On your system `mex` is configured to use the *lcc* compiler which is a C compiler. Boost is a C++ library; so you cannot compile programs that use Boost using *lcc*.

Run `mex -setup` and select a C++ compiler.

If you do not have any other compilers installed, you must first install one. On Windows, R2012B supports the free [Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express) C++ compiler. Download and install this, then try running the `mex` command again (after running `mex -setup`).